# Run autocmd on file close

Tags: neovim, autocmd

I've been looking through `:help autocmd-events` for an event that is going to be ran when a file is closed, but I got pretty confused, seeing there were many events that sound like they might do their job, but also that might not do it completely, for example: `BufUnload`, `BufWinLeave`, `BufLeave`, but their descriptions confuse me a bit.

What I am looking for is an autocmd that is going to be run on any writable file, excepting some filetypes that appear in a table, before the respective file is closed.

What autocmd event should I be using for this situation, and how would the pattern I mentioned look like? I'll be writing my config in Lua, but Vimscript solutions are welcome too, since I can translate them for myself later.

Comment: I suppose you have to use BufUnload and test in your function if the corresponding buffer ``<afile>`` filetype should be checked against your list.

Comment: I think you're going to have define "closed" a bit more carefully. As Matt perhaps ungraciously points out, vim doesn't quite have this concept. But vim has buffers, that can be hidden, unloaded, deleted, and wiped (assuming they are loaded to begin with), and windows, which can be entered and left. And then there's quitting vim altogether. So it _really_ depends on _when_ you want to do the thing.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Well, what I'm going to make that autocmd do is have it modify the file content just before closing the file, including Vim quitting. What I mean with closing.. uh, just when the file gets closed? For example when the file is no longer in my tab bar? Is that a good explanation? I kind of figured that possibly Vim doesn't know that, since I think that if it would've, there would've been a more straightforward autocmd event for it

Comment: This is a bad explanation, as it only shows that you have wrong assumptions. One thing is on screen, another one is in RAM, and another one is on disk. There is no single event that applies to all these three things at once. There could be some commands that affect them all. But event is something different. It doesn't say what command is executing, but it says what object has  its state changed.

Comment: @Andy3153 what tab bar? By default, the tabline (`:help tabline`) shows open tab pages. Perhaps you have a plugin that uses it to display buffers?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah, I am using a plugin, BarBar. I didn't mention it because I thought that all plugins that do tab bars do the same thing, is that not the case? And, for the previous comment, I guess the best out of those three might be in RAM? I really am not sure

Comment: @Andy3153 no, not all plugins (let alone "tab bars", probably an implementation of a `:help tabline` value) do the same thing. It might be worth it to figure out exactly what action you take that causes the file (probably a buffer name) to disappear from BarBar. I also highly recommend spending some more time with core vim and getting to know it's concepts. After `vimtutor`, if you don't like reading `:help` (I do, but hey), you might look at http://vimcasts.org, esp. http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-buffers/ and subsequent on windows, tabs

Answer (score 1):

1. Read `:h BufWinLeave` carefully
2. Read `:h BufUnload` carefully
3. Read `:h 'hidden'` carefully
4. ...
5. PROFIT